# How to access UI elements from CustomView inflated after async task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I've a `Fragment` that contains a `progress bar`(currently visibility - gone), a `button` and a an empty `LinearLayout` container. Like:

```
<LinearLayout id="@+id/ll"> </LinearLayout>
```

Functionality  is such, that on button click an `async task` gets executed.
On `postExecute()`, a custom view is inflated in the empty layout container `ll`. This custom view is defined in a separate class. Like:

```
class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout{
    Button b1;
}
```

In this layout there is a button, that starts another `async task (say, AS2)`.
Now, on `postExecute()` of AS2, I want to make the visibility of the progress bar `VISIBLE`.

So, how can I access the elements of Fragment in AS2?

**PS** - I've simplified the question by reducing the number of view elements that I want to access. I'm trying to avoid passing view elements first in AS1 & from there to AS2.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you have `AS1` and `AS2` as inner classes inside a global one (let's say `MainActivity`), so just create your custom views as class members of `MainActivity`. Then you will be able to access them inside `AS2` directly without needing to pass them through `AS1` before.

But if you have `AS1` et `AS2` in different classes, so create a custom constructor for each class, with your custom views as parameters of constructors. You will be obliged in that case to pass views from `AS1`'s `postExecute()` method to `AS2`. And that's not strange because AS2 depends on AS1's execution.